# Will iPhone X from TMobile A1865 or A1901 work globally?

Tags: unlock, iphone

I travel frequently between China and the US. I have T mobile in the US and Unicom in China.

According to [apple's official website](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT202909), the iPhone X (A1865) is the only model that works with China Unicom.

I plan to purchase an iPhone X with the option for Tmobile on Apple's website. According to [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/is-iphone-x-with-tmobile-the-a1865-or-the-a1901.2081774/), *iPhone X with T Mobile is supposed to be A1901*.

However, "[the iPhone X A1865 is considered the global phone as it works on both GSM and CDMA networks. This phone is also available as a SIM-free factory-unlocked version at Apple Store](https://www.techwalls.com/iphone-x-models-a1865-a1901-a1902-differences/)."

#### Which of these statements are true?

#### Which iPhone X model should I purchase if I am only interested in LTE?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.techwalls.com/iphone-x-models-a1865-a1901-a1902-differences/ you better buy A1865 which works globally:

> #### A1865
>
> The iPhone X A1865 is considered the global phone as it works on both GSM and CDMA networks. This phone is also available as a SIM-free factory-unlocked version at Apple Store
>
> #### A1901
>
> The iPhone X A1901 is the GSM version. It is available on AT&T and T-Mobile in the United States, as well as many other Europe and Asia countries.

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to Ask Different! We try to refrain from link only answers, as these decrease readability and are susceptible to link rot. Could you please add any relevant info to the body?

Answer (score -1):

An iPhone X from T-Mobile should work outside the US but just to make sure try asking T-Mobile to be sure